# Sorting and grouping in kotlin

Tags: sorting, kotlin, comparable

I have a list of objects in the kotlin and I want to sort them by number and then by string. Is there a way to do this? I've gone through hundreds of articles, but nothing works anywhere.

`myList.sortedWith(compareBy<Item> {it.name.id }.thenBy{it.name.secondname})`
This code do not works.

Of course myList is a type of Item.

Greetings

@EDIT

But what if I have 10 same ids? The code will not reach the .thenBy check. Is there a possibility to check a whole pair of fields?

Comment: Did you assign the result of `sortedWith()`: `myList = myList.sortedWith(...)`

Comment: of course I did this :)

Comment: what do you mean by saying "them by number and then by string"? How's different to sort them by string in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myList.sortedWith(compareBy<Item> {it.name.id }.thenBy{it.name.secondname})` returns a sorted **copy** of the list, but it doesn't modify the original one.

If you want the original list to be modified, you can either use `sortWith` instead of `sortedWith`:

```
myList.sortWith(compareBy<Item> { it.name.id }.thenBy { it.name.secondname })
```

Or reassign `myList` variable:

```
myList = myList.sortedWith(compareBy<Item> { it.name.id }.thenBy { it.name.secondname })
```

Comment: @CallMePedro I've just tested it. It does work. Can you provide a list that isn't sorted correctly?

Comment: Oh my love! My bad that I had overwritten code deeper in the code.. My bad Sorry :)

Comment: But what if I have 10 same ids? The code will not reach the .thenBy check? Is there a possibility to check a whole pair?

Comment: @CallMePedro `.thenBy` check will be used when `id`s are the same. For example, the following assertation passes successfully: `listOf(Item(1, "2"), Item(1, "1")).sortedWith(compareBy<Item> { it.name.id }.thenBy { it.name.secondname }) shouldBe listOf(Item(1, "1"), Item(1, "2"))`